# How do you set the cmd or powershell console location using .net?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, console-application, asp.net-4.0

I want to implement a .NET application that is a smarter version of CD.

So with `CD {target_dir}` the user changes their location in the console to the target directory.

I want to create a .net app with usage `SmartCd {target_dir_guess}` that will allow a user to type a directory guess, and the application will jump to the closest found match.

I've implemented the code to figure out what directory the user likely wants to jump to, but I am unable to find a method in the .NET BCL that allows me to move the user to the new target directory in the console.

Methods like, `Environment.CurrentDirectory` will change the working directory of the running .NET application, but that is not what I'm trying to do.

I want to leave the user in a DIFFERENT directory after the .NET application exits.

Is there any .NET API to do this?

Something like: `Console.ChangeDirectory(targetDirectory)`?

Comment: There is the `Get-Location` command for `Powershell`, but I am not entirely sure that's what you're asking for.

Comment: I understand you want to change current directory of the command line environment, not the one where your .NET app is executed. I don't know if it is even possible. I wouldn't be surprise if CD is a built-in.

Comment: An alternative would be to put in your .NET app all the code to retrieve / guess the folder, and execute it via a script which do a CD on that folder

Comment: PowerShell Core is open source, so you can review how it handles `cd` and implement the one you like, https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell. However, there should be little chance for command prompt.